# google map api 3 choosing the type of places using overlays

Tags: php, javascript, android, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I'm working on google map api 3 for android webview and manage to load the map and the markers dynamically from mysql database. I follow the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3). Now I want to add a function that displays overlays on the map. Each overlay corresponds for a particular type of markers. ex: restaurants, gasoline stations etc. When users tap on that overlay, he/she can  only see markers that was that type on the map. Now my problem is I don't know where to start. My idea is to change the php script:

```
SELECT * FROM markers WHERE type = type_of_desired_place
```

I don't know where to pass values from javascript to php. I want the markers to be updated if the users tap on that overlays.

Can someone help me? I'm new to google map. And if I'm wrong on some info, then please correct me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use a [MarkerManager](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/tags/markermanager/0.1/src/markermanager.js?r=31) , then once you have your pins in it, you need to have a trigger for the click on the overlay. Once this is down, you need to use Ajax to make new query to your Mysql server with new details for the info you want.

What i use is jQuery Ajax, you post the info with Ajax to a PHP page that will parse the request and return the proper data to recompile your pins.

I'm sorry i can't tell you every single details of the steps, but this is quit long to explain but if you start going in that direction you will get moving and be able to ask smaller steps at a time.

Good luck!